# Why do people apply Fubini-Tonelli theorem so easily?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm reading a text "Lebesgue Integration - Frank jones" from which i got recommended here, stackexchage.

This text seemingly covers various topics on measure theory, but i think that's it. This text seems student-friendly at the first glance, but the more i look careful, the more i found it very terse.

It's not even this text, but other texts don't really care about measurability.

Here's a phrase in a text

> "Frank Jones - Lebesgue Integration - p.203"
>
> Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ be positive real numbers.
>
> Let $f$ be a Lebesgue measurable function on $(0,\infty)$
>
> Let $ L =\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^{n+1}} {x_1}^{a_1-1}\cdots{x_{n-1}}^{a_{n-1}-1}dx_1\cdots dx_n \int_{x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}}^\infty f(t)(t-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1})^{a_n -1} dt$
>
> Then by Tonelli's theorem, $L =\int_0^\infty f(t) dt \int_{x_1+\cdots x_{n-1}<t \bigwedge x_k>0} {x_1}^{a_1-1}\cdots{x_{n-1}}^{a_{n-1}-1}(t-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1})^{a_n -1} dx_1\cdots dx_n$

I don't see any logic from second line to third line in the above phrase.

In order to apply Tonelli's theorem, it must be checked that $H((x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}),y) = f(y){x_1}^{a_1-1}\cdots{x_{n-1}}^{a_{n-1}-1}(t-x_1-\cdots-x_{n-1})^{a_n -1}$ is Lebesgue measurable on its natural domain

And i have no idea how to prove that this is measurable and posted a question about this and i haven't got any answer there. ( [How do i prove this mixture of Lebesgue measurable functions is Lebesgue measurable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690849/how-do-i-prove-this-mixture-of-lebesgue-measurable-functions-is-lebesgue-measura))

Why do people just neglect such hypothesis in Fubini's Theorem?

Comment: how do you claim that $H$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I have proved that "If $f$ is a $\mathfrak{M}$-measurable nonnegative function and $g$ is a $\Sigma$-measurable nonnegative function, then $h(x,y)=f(x)g(y)$ is a $\mathfrak{M}\otimes\Sigma$-measurable nonnegative function. However, in this case, $H$ is of the form $f(x,y)g(y)$. I have no idea how do prove that $H$ is measurable

Comment: You should see how it works in simpler cases.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I think i don't understand you. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Number8: Try to see how it works in the case of double integrals.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Isn't it a double integral in my post..? Even in  the case applying Fubini-Tonneli for $\mathbb{R}^2$, the same problem occurs.. Would you please see the link in the post and my comment to RobertIsrael's answer there?